# React Component underneath content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react.js and react router to render components on a certain route. In development all of my components show up, but in production on heroku my components render underneath each other, despite adding a z-index property. For example, The navbar and the home page is a component. This is a picture of the project in development. Everything shows up. The navbar has a z-index that is above all. [image]

Now when i pushed this project to production the navbar was rendered underneath the home component. [image]

I hope this question is clear, but i'm unsure why the component is rendered underneath.

Here is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Nav from './nav'
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import Gallery from './Gallery'
import Resume from './Resume'
import {Route, Router, BrowserRouter, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'




export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Nav/>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
            <Route exact path='/gallery' component={Gallery}/>
            <Route exact path='/resume' component={Resume}/>
          </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Underneath" where? Seems to me like the `Nav` component has disappeared in the second picture.

Comment: yeah, the nav component is being rendered but it is underneath the home component, but only in production. I was thinking about just pushing down the home component but i was curious as to why this would occur only in production